# Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: Cannot assign requested address (Address not available)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, docker

I have java application that connect to mysql on docker. when i run load test to save and update data to mysql, first it run corectly but, after a while i got the

> Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: Cannot assign requested address (Address not available)

and program exit immediately.

my program connect to mysql by hibernate and i used the following code to interact with database:

```
 Session curentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        curentTransaction = curentSession.beginTransaction();
        curentSession.update(entity);
        curentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: exception seems clear enough

Comment: But it happen after while, at first it work fine.

Answer (score 2):

It seem that when hibernate open session with **getcurrentSession()**, close it after transaction commit, but the tcp connection is still open with status of "TIME_WAIT" so when i run `netstat -natp` i got the huge number of connection to 3306 (mysql port). so i have two solution:

1. change the design of my connection to database that not close and reopen connection in each transaction.
2. change the time of connection wait in status "time_wait" with:

> echo 30 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fin_timeout

In addition i found that change the **tcp_fin_timeout** is not good solution in my case. i change the `dataSource` from ***DriverManagerDataSource*** to ***HikariDataSource*** and used the **maximumPoolSize** to manage the connection to mysql database.
so the problem of huge connection to mysql database gone away. ;)

good luck